# Force using fixed-width font in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, fonts

What's the simplest way of forcing Emacs org-mode to use the same fixed-width Font Family and Height everywhere (but keeping other properties distinct, like Foreground)?

I could make all `org-level-n` faces inherit from `fixed-pitch`, or make `variable-pitch` actually reference a fixed-width font, for instance, but that would be cumbersome, I guess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. Are you using a custom theme or the Emacs default? Some themes change certain faces, e.g. Org headings. Also, have you changed the default Emacs font or tweaked some faces? By default Emacs sets a fixed-width/monospace font.

Comment: Hey @undostres, I'm using [Bozhidar Batsov's Solarized for Emacs](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs).

Comment: Hmm, just as I thought. That theme introduces more "intrusive" changes than others. The README file in the repository shows some variables you can change to avoid some modifications, but if I recall correctly the variable-width font can't be changed. A workaround: use another Solarized implementation like [this one](https://github.com/purcell/color-theme-sanityinc-solarized) or [this one](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized). But if you don't want to switch themes, you'll need to apply some face changes above Batsov's theme.

Comment: @undostres Thanks man, you were right, problem was the color theme that I was using.

Comment: Sure! NP. I'm an Org heavy user and had the same issue with that theme. Finally decided to changed it instead of trying some hack (which can be done, nevertheless).

Comment: Set some settings in [Theme specific settings](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs#theme-specific-settings) to disable font size changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some themes change faces for no good reason.

For example, if you are using `Solarized` theme add code below before loading it.

```
(setq solarized-use-variable-pitch nil
      solarized-scale-org-headlines nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `face-remap-add-relative`; see the [Face Remapping](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html) section of the Emacs Lisp manual.

Here's a hook that sets the "family" property of the `default` face in Org mode buffers to "Monospace", effectively turning `default` into `fixed-pitch`.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda () (face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Monospace")))
```

Comment: Funny. For me, that had the opposite effect: all org fonts are now proportional (both headings and list items). Before that at least the list items were displayed with a monospace font.

Comment: I use `face-remap-add-relative` too, and it works for me (I don't have "Monospace" but use "Input Sans Mono" instead). There are also several other faces you might want to mess with, all named org-*something*.